# How to make ls produce ISO 8601 format

Tags: 12.04, ls

In older versions of Ubuntu, like 9.10, `ls(1)` produced ISO 8601 format by default, in the way

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso
```

does it.  With 12.04, we're back at the older Unix style. Thus replacing the year by minutes and seconds for recent dates.

How can I - in the least intrusive manner change this back to `long-iso`? Is there maybe some general configuration option?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I know this question is quite old (more than 1 year old), but for posterity, let me share the tip as originally described in [this blog post](http://rene.kabis.org/2011/05/07/linux-and-displaying-dates-in-iso-8601-format/) (not mine). In summary, this one line does everything you want:

```
export TIME_STYLE=long-iso
```

stick that line into `/etc/profile`, or a file in `/etc/profile.d/`, or even in `~/.bashrc`, and you're good to go.

Comment: or /etc/bash.bashrc alternate for system-wide config

Answer (score 22):

I was convinced that `ls` took its default arguments from the environment variable `LS_OPTIONS`, but its man page makes no mention of this.

My solution would be to set an alias to `ls` in `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='ls --time-style=long-iso'
```

Which instantly makes it work for the common `ll` alias as well.

Comment: +1, but isn't there a better, that is, more principled - Ubuntu style for this? U often puts another layer of config on top of it.