# ls command: Show time only (in iso-format)

Tags: command-line, ls

I found a way to show the date in iso-format: [How to make ls produce ISO 8601 format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268721/how-to-make-ls-produce-iso-8601-format)

Now I want to show only the time, not the columns before:

```
ls --time-style=long-iso  -l
drwxr-xr-x 11 foo foo  4096 2018-03-06 14:17 mydir
```

How can I make the output look like this?

```
2018-03-06 14:17 mydir
```

A solution without cut/grep/sed/awk/tr is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You can use cut to do this job for you pretty easily

```
hostname$ ls --time-style=long-iso  -l | cut -f 6- -d " "
2019-02-06 02:57 Desktop/
2019-02-07 02:08 Documents/
2019-02-08 04:02 Downloads/
2019-01-29 04:04 Pictures/
2018-12-15 13:35 VirtualBox VMs/
2019-02-08 03:34 custom-repo/
```

As was stated in the comments, this only works under certain circumstances. However I think this is something you can do with `awk` as well (I in no way claim to be an awkspert :-) nor am I even close to one) but I came up with this awk solution

```
hostname$ ls --time-style=long-iso  -la | awk '{print $6, $7, $8, $9}'
Jan 29 08:34 .xinitrc
Dec 17 17:55 .xinitrc.bkp
Feb 8 04:21 .zcompdump
Feb 8 04:58 .zdirs
Oct 11 16:51 .zprofile
Dec 10 10:17 .zsh_history
Feb 7 01:48 .zshrc.local
Feb 6 02:57 Desktop/
Feb 7 02:08 Documents/
Feb 8 04:02 Downloads/
Jan 29 04:04 Pictures/
Dec 15 13:35 VirtualBox
Feb 8 03:34 custom-repo/
```

which seems to work with conditions presented in comments

Comment: Basically correct but fails if you have one- and two-digit numbers (e.g. `5` and `10`) in the second column (of ls -l). Then the one-digit numbers are padded with blanks in front and `cut -f6- -d" "` _sees_ an empty column.

Comment: Nice! I'm not an _awkspert_ either ;-) but found this one: `awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; print}'`. It sets the first 5 fields to empty before printing.

Answer (score 4):

You can't with `ls` alone. But `find` has a `-printf` action that allows for custom output. See the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html), especially the section about `-printf format`.

```
me@ubuntu:~> find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %f\n'
2019-02-07 11:25 .
2019-02-05 18:58 foo.txt
2019-02-05 17:40 bar.txt
2019-01-22 16:47 other.file
2019-02-05 16:42 README.txt
```

Here `%TY` denotes the year of the file's modification time, `%Tm` the month, and so on. `%f` is the filename.
The `-maxdepth 1` avoids recursion.

Comment: `! -path .` excludes the cwd ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525004/how-to-exclude-this-current-dot-folder-from-find-type-d)) and the `-printf` argument can be shortened to `'%TF %TR %f\n'`. I don’t know why that’s not in `find`’s manpage, but well, it’s all just [strftime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/strftime.3.html)… :)

Comment: That `TF/TR` is a good finding. Thanks, @dessert.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat -c"%y %n"` and its output comes quite close to what you want, however without further processing it’s not exactly the same, e.g.:

```bsh
$ stat -c"%y %n" *
2019-02-08 00:36:58.025402641 +0100 file.docx
2019-02-08 00:36:55.845416494 +0100 file.txt
2019-02-02 16:50:59.572351725 +0100 test
```

To delete the seconds and time zone part you can use `sed` as follows:

```bsh
$ stat -c"%y %n" * | sed 's/:[^:]*+[0-9]*//'
2019-02-08 00:36 file.docx
2019-02-08 00:36 file.txt
2019-02-02 16:50 test
```

If you want to do that *reasonably*, i.e. without relying on text processing, you should use `date`. Note however that this calls both `stat` and `date` once for every single file/directory processed, which is not efficient.

```bsh
$ for i in *; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date -d@$(stat -c%Y "$i") +'%F %R')" "$i"; done
2019-02-08 00:36 file.docx
2019-02-08 00:36 file.txt
2019-02-02 16:50 test
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d`

should work nicely you can also use different date modifiers

this is according to `man ls`

```
show times using style STYLE: full-iso, long-iso, iso, locale, or +FORMAT;
```